# Error with Mechanize and Beautifulsoup httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '' (Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm going through a list of URLs and opening them with my script, using Mechanize/BeautifulSoup.

However I am getting this error:

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 718, in _set_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
httplib.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: ''
```

This happens at this line of code:

```
page = mechanize.urlopen(req)
```

The following is my code. Any insight into what I'm doing wrong? Many of the URLs work, it's when it hits certain ones that I get this error message, so not sure why.

```
from mechanize import Browser
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re, os
import shutil
import mechanize
import urllib2
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

mech = Browser()
linkfile = open ("links.txt")
urls = []
while 1:
    url = linkfile.readline()
    urls.append("%s" % linkfile.readline())
    if not url:
        break

for url in urls:
    if "http://" or "https://" not in url: 
        url = "http://" + url
    elif "..." in url:
    elif ".pdf" in url:
        #print "this is a pdf -- at some point we should save/log these"
        continue
    elif len (url) < 8:
        continue
    req = mechanize.Request(url)
    req.add_header('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0')
    req.add_header('Accept-Language', 'Accept-Language  en-US,en;q=0.5')
    try:
        page = mechanize.urlopen(req)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print "there was an error opening the URL, logging it"
        print e.code
        logfile = open ("log/urlopenlog.txt", "a")
        logfile.write(url + "," + "couldn't open this page" + "\n")
        pass
```

Comment: http://blog.21ic.com/more.asp?id=27916

Comment: Works for me... `http://blog.21ic.com/more.asp?id=27916` that is.

Comment: Does anyone know of a way that I can just keep going? It basically stops my whole script. It deosn't happen often (maybe 1/25 URLs)... But I want it to continue versus breaking.

Comment: It's a bit odd because I think the error from `page = mechanize.urlopen(req)` take time to propagate. It doesn't raise the error until I get further down into the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this piece of code

```
if "http://" or "https://" not in url:
```

isn't doing what you want (or what you think it will be doing).

```
if "http://"
```

will always evaluate to true, hence your URLs are never prefixed.
You need to rewrite it (for example) as:

```
if "https://" not in url and "http://" not in url:
```

Moreover, now that I started testing your piece:

```
urls = []
while 1:
    url = linkfile.readline()
    urls.append("%s" % linkfile.readline())
    if not url:
        break
```

This actually makes sure your URLs file is read improperly and every 2nd line is read in, you probably want this to read:

```
urls = []
while 1:
    url = linkfile.readline()
    if not url:
        break
    urls.append("%s" % url)
```

The reason to that is - you call `linkfile.readline()` twice, forcing it to read 2 lines and save only every 2nd line to your list.

Also, you want the `if` clause to be before appending, to prevent empty entry in the end of your list.

But your particular URL example works for me. For more, I'll probably need your links file.

Comment: I think you're right about that, but not sure that's what's causing the error... The URL's are prefixed when it tries to open them. I do a print statement to assure that.

Comment: See my edit. That particular URL works ok for me, so to help you out more I'll probably need your links file as is.